# In one of my React component I stuck with syntax error in my project

Tags: reactjs

In my React project I Created only one component manually that is Person.js, I am getting a syntax error in App.js component.

This is Person.js component

```
import React from 'react'

const person = () => {
    return <p>I'm person</p>
}

export default person
```

This is App.js component

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person'

function App() {
   state = {
    persons: [
      { name: 'Vamsi', age: 21 },
      { name: 'Shiva', age: 19 },
      { name: 'Angle', age: 24 }
    ]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Person name={this.state.persons[0].name}
          age={this.state.persons[0].age}>
        </Person>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[1].name}
          age={this.state.persons[1].age}>
        </Person>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[2].name}
          age={this.state.persons[2].age}>
        </Person>
        {/* <button>Switch Name</button> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

I am able to see syntax error in App.js component.

Comment: Can you include the error message

Comment: What is your folder structure?

Comment: Also check this - https://medium.com/@Zwenza/functional-vs-class-components-in-react-231e3fbd7108

Comment: Yes, I corrected from you only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line only,

```
function App() {
```

You cannot use `render` inside of `functional component`. `render` function is meant to be used in `class based component` only.

Just change that line to,

```
class App extends React.Component {
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-encxr?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 0):

Your App component should be declared as class type

Answer (score 0):

First:
Try to change:

```
function App() {
```

for

```
class App extends React.Component {
```

The render() function inherits from the React.Component class

App.js would stay like this

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Person from './Person/Person'

class App extends React.Component {
   state = {
    persons: [
      { name: 'Vamsi', age: 21 },
      { name: 'Shiva', age: 19 },
      { name: 'Angle', age: 24 }
    ]
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Person name={this.state.persons[0].name}
          age={this.state.persons[0].age}>
        </Person>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[1].name}
          age={this.state.persons[1].age}>
        </Person>
        <Person name={this.state.persons[2].name}
          age={this.state.persons[2].age}>
        </Person>
        {/* <button>Switch Name</button> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Second: If you are looking for each person component to print their name and age, you must add the following in Person.js

```
import React from 'react'

class Person extends React.Component {
    render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <p>I'm {this.props.name} and I'm {this.props.age} years old</p>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Person
```